# AX 2012 SSRS Choose which design to open

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Can I choose which design to open in ssrs reports, depending on parameters,  if the data source is a query?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just put the logic in an you can specify a design via this method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/how-to-specify-a-report-design-by-using-x-morphx-reporting-tools

The more common convention is to use `ssrsReportStr([SSRSReport],[Design])` and you can see an example here: `\Classes\AgreementConfirmController\main`